# facebook authentication: did user check "stay logged in"

Tags: facebook, facebook-authentication

I am adding facebook authentication to my website. Is there a way for me to know whether the user checked "stay logged in"?

```
    FB.login(function(response) {
       if (response.authResponse) {
         FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            // logged in
            KNOW HERE: Did user check 'stay logged in'?
         });
       }else {
       }
   });
```

Comment: No, there is no way for you to know that.

Comment: Thanks. Then I won't waste more time looking for a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be that it is not possible to determine.